# Best way to combine these 2 javascript functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, func, reusability

I'm trying to combine these 2 functions in an elegant way. I already reduce the complexity by using switch statement and const variable for repeating value

This functions subtracts day values by given day, week or 2week

```
const handleLeft = (
  active: any,
  setActiveDate: any,
  setParagonActiveDate: any
) => {
  const time = (prevDay: any, length: number) =>
    moment(prevDay)
      .subtract(length, 'd')
      .format('YYYY/MM/DD');
  switch (active) {
    case 'day':
      setActiveDate((prevDay: any) => time(prevDay, 1));
      setParagonActiveDate &&
        setParagonActiveDate((prevDay: any) => time(prevDay, 1));
      break;
    case 'week':
      setActiveDate((prevDay: any) => time(prevDay, 6));
      setParagonActiveDate &&
        setParagonActiveDate((prevDay: any) => time(prevDay, 6));
      break;
    case '2weeks':
      setActiveDate((prevDay: any) => time(prevDay, 13));
      setParagonActiveDate &&
        setParagonActiveDate((prevDay: any) => time(prevDay, 13));
  }
};
```

This functions adds day values by given day, week or 2week

```
const handleRight = (
  active: any,
  setActiveDate: any,
  setParagonActiveDate?: any
) => {
  const time = (prevDay: any, length: number) =>
    moment(prevDay)
      .add(length, 'd')
      .format('YYYY/MM/DD');
  switch (active) {
    case 'day':
      setActiveDate((prevDay: any) => time(prevDay, 1));
      setParagonActiveDate &&
        setParagonActiveDate((prevDay: any) => time(prevDay, 1));
      break;
    case 'week':
      setActiveDate((prevDay: any) => time(prevDay, 6));
      setParagonActiveDate &&
        setParagonActiveDate((prevDay: any) => time(prevDay, 6));
      break;
    case '2weeks':
      setActiveDate((prevDay: any) => time(prevDay, 13));
      setParagonActiveDate &&
        setParagonActiveDate((prevDay: any) => time(prevDay, 13));
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference is whether you do `.subtract` or `.add` after `moment`, which you can do in a single function using the conditional operator inside bracket notation and a fourth argument:

```
const handleLeftOrRight = (
    active: any,
    setActiveDate: any,
    setParagonActiveDate: any,
    add: boolean
  ) => {
    const time = (prevDay: any, length: number) =>
      moment(prevDay)
        [add ? 'add' : 'subtract'](length, 'd')
        .format('YYYY/MM/DD');
    // rest of your code
  };
```

Then use, eg

```
handleLeftOrRight(active, setActiveDate, setParagonActiveDate, true)
```

instead of

```
handleRight(active, setActiveDate, setParagonActiveDate)
```

and the same for passing `false` as a fourth argument instead of `handleLeft`.

But since you're using TypeScript, I'd also highly recommend typing things properly, to actually take advantage of TypeScript's type system - in TypeScript, it's almost always a good idea to avoid `any`, since it's not type-safe - it can be assigned to anything and used anywhere, opening up the possibility of type-related runtime errors or bugs. For example, `active` can be either `'day'`, `'week'`, or `'2weeks'`, so you can do:

```
const handleLeftOrRight = (
    active: 'day' | 'week' | '2weeks',
```

instead of using `any`.

Another way to improve the code and make things a lot DRYer would be to have an object mapping the `active` value to the second argument passed to `time`.

```
const daysByActive = {
    day: 1,
    week: 6,
    '2weeks': 13
}
const handleLeftOrRight = (
    active: 'day' | 'week' | '2weeks',
    setActiveDate: any,
    setParagonActiveDate: any, // this might be improved by changing to boolean?
    add: boolean
) => {
    const time = (prevDay: any, length: number) =>
        moment(prevDay)
            [add ? 'add' : 'subtract'](length, 'd')
            .format('YYYY/MM/DD');
    const days = daysByActive[active];
    setActiveDate((prevDay: any) => time(prevDay, days));
    if (setParagonActiveDate)
        setParagonActiveDate((prevDay: any) => time(prevDay, days));
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the thoughtful explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can consume a `add`|`subtract` boolean argument, to be used as a dynamic property to determine which `moment` object function to use. Other than this there is no difference between the two functions.

```
const handleLeftRight = (
  active: any,
  setActiveDate: any,
  setParagonActiveDate: any,
  add: boolean
) => {
  const time = (prevDay: any, length: number) =>
    moment(prevDay)[add ? 'add' : 'subtract'](length, 'd')
      .format('YYYY/MM/DD');

  switch (active) {
    case 'day':
      setActiveDate((prevDay: any) => time(prevDay, 1));
      setParagonActiveDate &&
        setParagonActiveDate((prevDay: any) => time(prevDay, 1));
      break;
    case 'week':
      setActiveDate((prevDay: any) => time(prevDay, 6));
      setParagonActiveDate &&
        setParagonActiveDate((prevDay: any) => time(prevDay, 6));
      break;
    case '2weeks':
      setActiveDate((prevDay: any) => time(prevDay, 13));
      setParagonActiveDate &&
        setParagonActiveDate((prevDay: any) => time(prevDay, 13));
  }
};
```